# Does componentDidCatch() catches error from promise or event handler binded to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-16

On React 16, let's say I have a component like

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
      throw new Error("Oh nooo!");
    });
  };

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
     alert(error)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        Name: {this.props.user.name}
      </div>
  );
}
```

}

and then in the constructor I do `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)`. Will the error be catched in `componentDidCatch()` ?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Answer (score 1):

Now, it only catches errors in the components below them in the tree.

See: [Error Handling in React 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html)